# Not able to overlay two layers of map in R

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, r-sp

This is my sample code

```
library(spData)

world_asia = world[world$continent == "Asia", ]
asia = st_union(world_asia)

plot(world["pop"], reset = FALSE)
plot(asia, add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

The error I get is :

```
Error in polypath(p_bind(L), border = border[i], lty = lty[i], lwd = lwd[i], : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Someone please help me solve this basic problem. Could be more benefitting if u can explain why this error comes. thanks in advance

Comment: can't reproduce.  Works fine for me.  Try restarting R session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I was using the code in markdown chunk and was running the code line by line instead of running the entire chunk (ctrl+shift+enter)

Answer: run the entire chunk there wont be any problem.